# Add Total column between table after same id's

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

NET MVC, I have one table, I want to calculate amount of similar Id's in row     total.

```
| Id | Name | amount |
| -- | ---- | ------ |
| 1  | abc  |  1000  |
| 1  | xyz  |  2000  |
| 2  | mno  |  1000  |
| 3  | ams  |  500   |
| 3  | dky  |  400   |
```

I print this in MVC View using for each loop

```
   foreach(var item in Model){
      <tr>@item.id</tr>
      <tr>@item.Name</tr>
      <tr>@item.amount</tr>
   }
```

but I want to display table like :-

```
| Id | Name | amount |
| -- | ---- | ------ |
| 1  | abc  |  1000  |
| 1  | xyz  |  2000  |
|total         3000  |
| 2  | mno  |  1000  |
|total         1000  |
| 3  | ams  |  500   |
| 3  | dky  |  400   |
|total         900   |
```

what should I do for adding that total row after similar ID,s and calculate total amount of that ID?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";

    var groups = Model.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(g => new
    {
        Id = g.Key,
        Items = g.ToList(),
        Total = g.Sum(x => x.Amount)
    });
}

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            foreach(var item in group.Items)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.Id</td>
                    <td>@item.Name</td>
                    <td>@item.Amount</td>
                </tr>
            }
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">Total</td>
                <td>@group.Total</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```